# prime decomposition in even dihedral extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number fields of degree $n$ with $n$ an even integer such that the normal closure of $L$ has the Galois group isomorphic to $D_n$, the dihedral group of order $2n$. Is there any result about the decomposition form of a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ in $L$?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you're looking for?  Do you understand the general situation for relating splitting in $L/K$ to splitting in the Galois closure?  If not, I'd say this is more appropriate for MathStackExchange.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I'm looking for an explicit decomposition form in "even dihedral extensions L/K" (or in the Galois closure of L over K) as in Cohen's book (Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory, Proposition 10.1.26) the decomposition form of primes in a "prime order" dihedral extensions  is formulated.